# Printing multiple barcodes in windows form application .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, barcode

[image]

below is my code

Draw method is below:
Now when I generate the code it replaces the existing barcode and does not place a new barcode on picture box.

```
System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control), new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50));
ean13.Scale = 1.0F;
ean13.DrawEan13Barcode(g, new System.Drawing.Point(a, a));
public void DrawEan13Barcode( System.Drawing.Graphics g, System.Drawing.Point pt )
{
    float width = this.Width * this.Scale;
    float height = this.Height * this.Scale;

    //  EAN13 Barcode should be a total of 113 modules wide.
    float lineWidth = width / 113f;

    // Save the GraphicsState.
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsState gs = g.Save( );

    // Set the PageUnit to Inch because all of our measurements are in inches.
    g.PageUnit = System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;

    // Set the PageScale to 1, so a millimeter will represent a true millimeter.
    g.PageScale = 1;

    System.Drawing.SolidBrush brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush( System.Drawing.Color.Black );

    float xPosition = 0;

    System.Text.StringBuilder strbEAN13 = new System.Text.StringBuilder( );
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbTemp = new System.Text.StringBuilder( );

    float xStart = pt.X;
    float yStart = pt.Y;
    float xEnd = 0;

    System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font( "Arial", this._fFontSize * this.Scale );

    // Calculate the Check Digit.
    this.CalculateChecksumDigit( );

    sbTemp.AppendFormat( "{0}{1}{2}{3}", 
        this.CountryCode,
        this.ManufacturerCode,
        this.ProductCode, 
        this.ChecksumDigit );


    string sTemp = sbTemp.ToString( );

    string sLeftPattern = "";

    // Convert the left hand numbers.
    sLeftPattern = ConvertLeftPattern( sTemp.Substring( 0, 7 ) );

    // Build the UPC Code.
    strbEAN13.AppendFormat( "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{1}{0}",
        this._sQuiteZone, this._sLeadTail,
        sLeftPattern,                   
        this._sSeparator,
        ConvertToDigitPatterns( sTemp.Substring( 7 ), this._aRight ) );

    string sTempUPC = strbEAN13.ToString( );

    float fTextHeight = g.MeasureString( sTempUPC, font ).Height;

    // Draw the barcode lines.
    for( int i = 0; i < strbEAN13.Length; i++ )
    {
        if( sTempUPC.Substring( i, 1 ) == "1" )
        {
            if( xStart == pt.X )
                xStart = xPosition;

            // Save room for the UPC number below the bar code.
            if( ( i > 12 && i < 55 ) || ( i > 57 && i < 101 ) )
                // Draw space for the number
                g.FillRectangle( brush, xPosition, yStart, lineWidth, height - fTextHeight );
            else
                // Draw a full line.
                g.FillRectangle( brush, xPosition, yStart, lineWidth, height );
        }

        xPosition += lineWidth;
        xEnd = xPosition;
    }

    // Draw the upc numbers below the line.
    xPosition = xStart - g.MeasureString( this.CountryCode.Substring( 0, 1 ), font ).Width;
    float yPosition = yStart + ( height - fTextHeight );

    // Draw 1st digit of the country code.
    g.DrawString( sTemp.Substring( 0, 1 ), font, brush, new System.Drawing.PointF( xPosition, yPosition ) );

    xPosition += ( g.MeasureString( sTemp.Substring( 0, 1 ), font ).Width + 43 * lineWidth ) -
        ( g.MeasureString( sTemp.Substring( 1, 6 ), font ).Width );

    // Draw MFG Number.
    g.DrawString( sTemp.Substring( 1, 6 ), font, brush, new System.Drawing.PointF( xPosition, yPosition ) );

    xPosition += g.MeasureString( sTemp.Substring( 1, 6 ), font ).Width + ( 11 * lineWidth );

    // Draw Product ID.
    g.DrawString( sTemp.Substring( 7 ), font, brush, new System.Drawing.PointF( xPosition, yPosition ) );

    // Restore the GraphicsState.
    g.Restore( gs );
}


public System.Drawing.Bitmap CreateBitmap( )
{
    float tempWidth = ( this.Width * this.Scale ) * 100 ;
    float tempHeight = ( this.Height * this.Scale ) * 100;

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap( (int)tempWidth, (int)tempHeight );

    System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage( bmp );
    this.DrawEan13Barcode( g, new System.Drawing.Point( 0, 0 ) );
    g.Dispose( );
    return bmp;
}
```

if there is an alternative way of doing this, requirement is clear

draw and print N number of barcodes using windows forms

Comment: You're replacing the current picture with a new one each time. A picturebox can only hold one picture.

Comment: @bwoogie yes I know, I want alternative solution to print the barcodes.

Comment: why don't you just create a loop in `CreateBitmap`? i.e. make `DrawEan13Barcode` return `yPosition` then pass it to the next call to `DrawEan13Barcode` as the staring y

Comment: So then, go ahead and display multiple barcode images. You know how to display one. Now perform that N times. In case you don't care to understand the code you posted, hire a developer to help you out.

Comment: @IInspectable sounds simple in theory, I am developer myself... problem comes with the position of display, I can't manage the positions

I tried creating bitmap image but dumped image is blank... I used bitmap.getthumbnails image

Comment: *"I know how to do* x *. I need to do* x N *times."* - No matter how you look at it, it is trivially simple in practice, too. Maybe your real problem is, that you are having difficulty properly abstracting your problem. This question certainly hints towards that.

Answer (score -2):

you can generate barcode and save its image in database sql server.
then create crystal report and get that field on crystal report detail section. you will get what you need.

Comment: If a SQL database is all you have, everything looks like a query

Comment: I tried to dump the image on directory using bitmap.getthunbnails but it shows nothing